# why not work time of spinner Widgets?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to use the time spinner widget from: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time

I copied the code from the site and pasted into Notepad and convert Extension file to ".html".  But, when I tried to use it, it didn't work.  Why?

Comment: How exactly did you try to use the code?

Comment: Did you include jQuery/jQuery UI?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. He pasted into notepad, can't you read? `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup you pasted into an HTML file contains several URLs that do not explicitly specify a server name:

```
<script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/demos/external/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/demos/external/globalize.culture.de-DE.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

These will not be properly resolved since the markup comes from your local machine instead of being served by jQuery UI's server. Try prepending the scheme and the host:

```
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/external/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/external/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/external/globalize.culture.de-DE.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Comment: thank you But I wonder you how found error